# XMLHttpRequest setRequestHeader() --> is there a way to set the header value, instead of appending to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, xmlhttprequest

from:  http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-setrequestheader-method

```
client.setRequestHeader() 
    Appends an header to the list of author request headers, or if
    header is already in the list of author request headers, combines 
    its value with value.
```

Q. Is there a way to just *set* a header instead of appending to the existing one?

The code I'm working with is below, which is basically copied and pasted from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
     ...

     // xhr is an XMLHttpRequest object
     xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
}
```

Comment: Headers are usually sent by the server and parsed by the client. What are you trying to do? What's the point of setting a header on the client?

Comment: read the first sentence of the Django link in my description...  (its exactly what im trying to do,  e.g. set an X-CSRFToken header if it's not there for some weird reason)

Comment: Can you please elaborate this sentence? `Is there a way to just set a header instead of appending to the existing one?` The Django code appears to be `set`ting the `request` `header` with `setRequestHeader` already.

Comment: that snippet is jQuery, and I already did!  look at the top- I pasted in the link to the w3c spec and description for the setRequestMethod() in the XMLHTTPRequest object

Comment: `setRequestHeader` literally *sets* that request header. It appends if the value is *already* present, so you don't overwrite/lose the original header, but the `X-CSRF-Token` header won't be there, so it won't append. What's the issue here?

Comment: yeah thats totally right, but in my case the X-CSRF-Token *is* actually present, so the result is the csrftoken being concatenated twice!   So probalby what I'm looking for is something like...   if(xhr.doesNotHaveRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken') {  /* insert csrf header here */ }

Comment: dunno, maybe it's not possible   ...but I think I'm having the same problem here:  https://github.com/divio/django-cms/pull/1083   (the thing that prompted this post was a django-cms admin UI issue)

Comment: @DavidLam I'm having the issue as you explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027823/getting-duplicated-request-header-values-when-setting-it-with-cypress
Where you able to solve this?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal it was 9 years ago!  your guess is as good as mine! =D

Comment: @DavidLam hahahaha damn! So you ever figured it out? :)